# Is it always true that $|ab| = |a|\;|b|$, for real $a$ and $b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I write $| x^{2}-1|=|x-1| \cdot |x+1| $, would it be correct? Does it always work $| a\cdot b|=|a| \cdot |b| $ ?

Comment: It's ok if $a=x$ or $a=-x$ :)

Comment: in which case it would not work?

Comment: Oh, I corrected it, I meant x not a

Comment: Yes $|a\cdot b| = |a|\cdot |b|$.  Always.  I'm wondering if you are confusing this with $\sqrt{a\cdot b}$ not necessarily equalling $\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b}$.  But that is an *entirely* different situation.

Comment: @NemanjaDjordjevic Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is correct indeed

- $a,b$ both positive $\implies | a\cdot b|=a\cdot b=|a| \cdot |b|$
- $a,b$ both negative $\implies | a\cdot b|=a\cdot b=|a| \cdot |b|$
- $a,b$ with different sign $\implies | a\cdot b|=-a\cdot b=|a| \cdot |b|$

the case $a=0 \lor b=0$ is trivial.

Comment: Works if $a,b \in \mathbb C$ as well.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks to have pointed out that! What is the straightforward way to show that?

Comment: It might be above the OP's comfort level but if $z=a+bi$ then $z\overline z=a^2 + b^2 \in \mathbb R^+$ and $|z|$ is defined as $\sqrt{z\overline z}$.  If $w = b+ci$ then $\overline{zw}=\overline{(ac-bd) +(bc+ad)i}=(ac-bd) -(bc+ad)i=(a+bi)(c-di)=(a-bi)(c+di)=z\overline w=\overline zw$ so $|z||w|=\sqrt{z\overline z}\sqrt{w\overline w}=\sqrt{(z\overline w)(\overline zw)}=|zw|$

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for that generalization!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this follows directly from the definitions of absolute value. You can verify that $|ab|=|a||b|$ by writing $a=\mbox{sgn}(a)|a|$ and $a=\mbox{sgn}(b)|b|$, and verifying both sides give the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for all $a,b\in\Bbb{R}$ you have $|a\cdot b|=|a|\cdot|b|$
because it clearly holds when $a,b\geq0$ and
$$|a\cdot b|=|(-a)\cdot b|=|a\cdot(-b)|=|(-a)\cdot(-b)|,$$
and
$$|a|\cdot|b|=|-a|\cdot|b|=|a|\cdot|-b|=|-a|\cdot|-b|.$$